# DevExpress' javaScript function Hide and Show for Hyperlink Control

Tags: devexpress

I would like to use javaScript to hide and show regular DevExpress controls such as ASPxHyperlink on client side.  Please advise me if DevExpress has any javaScript functions that are equivalent to Hide() and Show() which are often used to hide and display popUp Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a ClientInstanceName in your markup as follows:

```
<dx:ASPxHyperlink id="hplButton" ... ClientInstanceName="hplButton" />
```

DevExpress renders a JavaScript object with the corresponding ClientInstanceName, so the JavaScript to show/hide would be as follows:

```
function showButton() {
  hplButton.Show();
}

function hideButton() {
  hplButton.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the super quick reply.